# How to determine the newest folder by date in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of directories which contain the last 5 days backed up.  How can I get only the most recent directory (06-01) below to process?

```
\\ds418\Backups\Emby\Emby Backup - 2020-06-01 02.0.0 - Auto
\\ds418\Backups\Emby\Emby Backup - 2020-05-31 02.0.0 - Auto
\\ds418\Backups\Emby\Emby Backup - 2020-05-30 02.0.0 - Auto
\\ds418\Backups\Emby\Emby Backup - 2020-05-29 02.0.0 - Auto
\\ds418\Backups\Emby\Emby Backup - 2020-05-28 02.0.0 - Auto
```

Comment: does the file datetime info work for your purpose? that is the easiest method.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, `$NewDir` will contain the most recent directory.

```
$PlaylistPath = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "$EmbyBackupDir" -Filter "Emby Backup*" | Sort-Object


foreach ($PLP in $PlaylistPath) {
   $NewDir = $PLP
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### *** All commands executed from \\ds418\Backups\Emby\ ***

If the directory naming is as simple as your example, then the most recent date will always be the last in an alpha sort. As that is the default sort order for Get-ChildItem, the following will suffice:

```
( Get-ChildItem -Directory )[-1].FullName
```

or

```
(gci -dir)[-1].FullName
```

If you actually need to find & parse the date in the directory name, here's one way:

```
gci -dir | select FullName, @{ N = 'FolderDate' ; E = {
    If ( $_.Name -match '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}' ) {
       [DateTime]$matches[0]
    }  
 }} | sort FolderDate | select -expand FullName -last 1
```